# How to format a double Value upto 2 decimal places in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am extracting double data from sqlite3 database. But I want to display it only upto two decimal places. So how to truncate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use sprintf formatting with NSString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", myValue];

Comment: Much simplier than messing around w/ NSNumberFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

See [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It formats numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Ben beat me to it!  You might also find this http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html useful.