# Limit a double to two decimal places without trailing zeros

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, decimal, nsnumberformatter

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113408/limit-a-double-to-two-decimal-places) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194855/how-to-format-a-double-value-upto-2-decimal-places-in-iphone). I want this exactly:

> 1.4324 => "1.43"
> 9.4000 => "9.4"
> 43.000 => "43"
>
> 9.4 => "9.40" (wrong)
> 43.000 => "43.00" (wrong)

In both questions the answers points to `NSNumberFormatter`. So it should be easy to achieve, but not for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 20)];

    NSNumberFormatter *doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadAfterSuffix];
    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setFormatWidth:2];

    NSNumber *myValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01234];
    //NSNumber *myValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.1];

    myLabel.text = [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue];

    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];
    myLabel = nil;
    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces release];
    doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces = nil;
}
```

I also tried it with

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2lf", [myValue doubleValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", resultString);
```

So how can I format double values with maximum two decimal places? If the last position contains a zero the zero should be left out.

**Solution:**

```
NSNumberFormatter *doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber *myValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01234];
NSLog(@"%@",[doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue]];
[doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces release];
doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces = nil;
```

Comment: Do you want rounding? That is should 1.4363 => "1.43" or "1.44"?

Comment: I think that would make sense.

Comment: Do not forget to release doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces after all...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try adding the following line, when configuring your formatter:

```
    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = @"0.##";
NSNumber *num = @(total_Value);
```

Comment: pl explain your answer

Comment: @SahilMittal Above code NSNumberFormatterRoundDown return value without round, then positiveFormat only give two fraction point value.

Answer (score 0):

How about trimming the unwanted characters from the end of the string?:

```
NSString* CWDoubleToStringWithMax2Decimals(double d) {
    NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", d];
    NSCharacterSet* cs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharacterInString:@"0."];
    NSRange r = [s rangeOfCharacterInSet:cs
                                 options:NSBackwardsSearch | NSAnchoredSearch];
    if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
      s = [s substringToIndex:r.location];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Even though this solution works there's a much better solution (see accepted answer)